# ArcPy CAD to File Geodatabase conversion error 000732?

Tags: arcpy, convert, file-geodatabase, autocad, error-000732

I have 19 unprojected CAD files in a Folder. Some are .dwg and .dxf extension. I am attempting to convert these CAD files to a GDB using the `arcpy.CADToGeodatabase_conversion()` tool

[image]

I wrote this little script below and it gives me an error

```
import arcpy
import os
CADpath = 'path\\CADstuff'
GDB = 'path\\CAD.gdb'
sr = '3424'
for cad in os.listdir(CADpath):
    cadname = str(cad[:-4])
    arcpy.CADToGeodatabase_conversion(cad, GDB, cadname,'',sr)
    print cadname




  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "path\CADtoGDB.py", line 9, in <module>
    arcpy.CADToGeodatabase_conversion(cad, GDB, cadname,reference_scale,sr)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.2\arcpy\arcpy\conversion.py", line 1637, in CADToGeodatabase
    raise e
ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 000732: Input CAD Datasets: Dataset 080401_DLU_2012-06-21.dwg does not exist or is not supported
Failed to execute (CADToGeodatabase).
```

*GDB created before script
*First time working with CAD files

Comment: trying adding this into your script `arcpy.env.workspace = CADpath` before you start the loop.

Comment: wow that worked! put it as an answer il accept it. Can you elaborate on why that worked? i have written standalone python scripts without defining the work space and they have worked before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As is - your script is just pushing in `filename.dwg` into the CAD tool. The CAD tool has no idea where to find this file. Its like me saying "I live on 5th Street". By adding in `arcpy.env.workspace = CADpath`, you're telling the tool where to look. Like saying "I live in New York City", thus you know what city to look for 5th Street.

```
import arcpy
import os
CADpath = 'path\\CADstuff'
GDB = 'path\\CAD.gdb'
sr = '3424'
arcpy.env.workspace = CADpath
for cad in os.listdir(CADpath):
    cadname = str(cad[:-4])
    print cadname
    arcpy.CADToGeodatabase_conversion(cad, GDB, cadname,'',sr)
```

I'd also move the print cadname up. That way it'll show he name its working on *before* trying to run the tool. It may have given you a clue that the path wasn't fully qualified and the tool couldnt find the dataset.

Or you could fully qualify the file path....

```
import arcpy
import os
CADpath = 'path\\CADstuff'
GDB = 'path\\CAD.gdb'
sr = '3424'
for cad in os.listdir(CADpath):
    cadname = str(cad[:-4])
    print cadname
    arcpy.CADToGeodatabase_conversion(os.path.join(CADpath, cad), GDB, cadname,'',sr)
```